# Which FIMSynchronization Service Accounts should be used

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, fim, ups

I am having a problems with UPS I've configured it correctly on production and UAT, everything works perfectly! The problems starts when I am trying to configure UPS for both my TESING and DEV machines because,(maybe that is the reason I am not sure) for DEV and TESTING I am using one account from installing to configuring all service applications. I keep getting the same error that UPS failed to start. does it matter if I am using the same account for everything? Both DEV and Testing are multi-server farms.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: is it sync service failed to start or sync with AD failed?

Comment: it's the Sync before I can even add a connection it's telling me to wait for the sync to finish

Comment: could you please check what error you getting in the Event Logs? also is your account is in local admin on the server where you are starting the sync service?

Comment: Yes it is and it it keeps being on  starting all the time

Comment: check the Event log and SharePoint uls logs for more clue